# Trying to find a number in an array with an input and print if it is not equal to the input

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make my program so you can input a number then get an output on the basis that if the input is equal to the number in the array it will print: "Value 7 is found in the array". If the value is not in the array it should say "Value X was not found in the array".

I am only getting the output that the value was not found in the array. Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code for this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int [] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        
        System.out.print("Enter a number you would like to search for: ");
        int num = reader.nextInt();
        
        if (num == array[0]) 
        System.out.println("Value " + num + "is in the array.");
        else
        System.out.println("Value " + num + " was not found in the array"); 
}
```

Comment: All you do is check if the first element of your array is equal to the input.

Comment: Ah I see, this was the only way I could get my if statement to work. I'm not able to do [0, 10]. How would I go about checking for the whole array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is comparing the user's input with just the first element of the array, i.e. `array[0]`. What you need to do is to loop through the whole array and compare the number with every element of the array.